# In ExtJS, Using a DataView, How Can You Detect A Key Held Down?

Tags: javascript, extjs

All, Using Ext JS (3.2), how is it possible to detect whether a user is pressing/holding down a specific key whilst performing another action with a DataView component?

The specific application is to see whether the control/shift key is depressed when a right click event occurs on a DataView node, if it is, the node is selected along with any others currently selected, if not- it replaces all other selections.

Many thanks in advance for the response!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the event object for properties like `shiftKey`, `ctrlKey`, `altKey`, etc. So it would be something like this (untested):

```
myDataView.on('contextmenu', function(dv, idx, node, e){
    if(e.shiftKey){
        // shift is pressed
    }
});
```